# Leftbar theorem environment with changeable colors for the left bar

Tags: environments

I'm writing some lecture notes and I would like a left bar environment for theorems and definitions with a changeable color for the left bar and the inside (white or grey).

I found this code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.90}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection} % important bit
\usepackage{framed}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{% 
\def\FrameCommand 
{%

    {\hspace{-3pt}\color{black}\vrule width 3pt}%
    \hspace{0pt}%must no space.
    \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{lightgray}%
}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
\begin{theorem}
Fun Math
\end{theorem}
\end{leftbar}
\begin{theorem}
Fun Math
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to change the leftbar color for every environment (green for definition and red for theorem) or even the inside. And I want some thing where I won't have to write `\begin{leftbar} ... \end{leftbar}` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) an option? It provides powerful theorem-like environments so that you can, for example, produce

[image]

with the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definition}%
   {theorem style=plain,enhanced,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=yellow!20!white,
    coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,
    drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white,boxrule=0.4pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{green}
   }{D}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}%
   {theorem style=plain,enhanced,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=yellow!20!white,
    coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,
    drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white,boxrule=0.4pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
   }{T}

\begin{document}

  \begin{defn}{defn title}{mydef}
    Fun Math
  \end{defn}

  A reference \ref{D:mydef}

  \begin{theorem}{theorem title}{mytheorem}
    Fun Math
  \end{theorem}

  A reference \ref{T:mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

As requested in the comments, you can remove the frame border by making it the same colour as the background and you can change the semicolon `:` to a `.` by setting the `terminator sign`. This gives:

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definition}%
   {theorem style=plain,enhanced,colframe=yellow!20!white,colback=yellow!20!white,
    coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,
    drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white, terminator sign={.},
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{green}
   }{D}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}%
   {theorem style=plain,enhanced,colframe=yellow!20!white,colback=yellow!20!white,
    coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,
    drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white,terminator sign={.},
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
   }{T}

\begin{document}

  \begin{defn}{defn title}{mydef}
    Fun Math
  \end{defn}

  A reference \ref{D:mydef}

  \begin{theorem}{theorem title}{mytheorem}
    Fun Math
  \end{theorem}

  A reference \ref{T:mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

You may also want to drop the `drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white` to remove the "shadow" under the theorem boxes.

Comment: It's actually perfect since I'm already using it for other stuff. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: A silly question xd. How to replace the 2 dots with only one and removes the borders with only the left bar ?

Comment: Yes, english isn't m first language xd. I don't know why the section number counter doesn't ...

Comment: @Solarwitness Um, I'm not xd !? I'll add an edit that shows how to do this.